# Highcharts don't hide categories labels on overflow

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using bar chart with Highcharts 4.0.4.
When categories labels are to close to each other half of them disappear. I want to disable this behaviour because there is plenty of space.
I've tried to search Highcharts documentations with: overflow, crop, clip, hide and so on. Nothing seems to fit in.

Examples:

`height: 260px;`
http://jsfiddle.net/t1wtLLnc/3/

`height: 230px;`
http://jsfiddle.net/t1wtLLnc/2/

As you can see in second example only 5 of 10 categories are shown.

Comment: Do you have some example code? How to replicate?

Comment: @wergeld I've added examples.

Comment: In both of those examples I see cat1, 3, 7, 9. You wish to have all visible, yes?

Comment: @wergeld yes. I guess it depends on browser. I've changed first example to fit all categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to force the chart to show all categories regardless of available space set the [`xAxis.labels.step`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.step) to 1.

Here is code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5', 'cat6', 'cat7', 'cat8', 'cat9', 'cat10'],
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                step: 1
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'ser1',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2, 34, 54, 41, 105, 20]
        }, ]
    });
});
```

And here is sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1wtLLnc/4/).

Note that you can run into issues with cramping up of text. We manipulate the spacingLeft and margins to accommodate long titles. In some cases we are forced to increase height of chart.